# How to keep disappearing Flutter Bottom Navigation and AppBar after navigating from subpages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom Tab bar in my app for navigation and appbar, from the menu page after adding products in Cart screen there is Continue button when i pressed it take me to Login screen, there a normal login with and otp verification, now when i try to navigate back to menu screen after successfull otp verification, i see Tab bar disappeared and the App bar.

How i can fix this problem

Cart Screen

```
return Scaffold
  ....
  row
    ...

   Container showOrderConfirmationBtn(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.transparent, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1.0),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          isLoggedIn == false
              ? Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()))
              : Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CarConfirmationCompletePage()));
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Wrap(
                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Continue',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'BuffetRegular',
                        fontSize: 13,
                        letterSpacing: 0.5),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login Screen

return Scafold
....

```
GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                final prefs =
                                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                                final customerData = LoginModel(
                                    mobile: maskFormatter.getUnmaskedText());

                                final result = await loginServices
                                    .loginCustomer(customerData);

                                final customerId = result['id'];

                                if (result['existsFlag'] == '1') {

                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => OtpVerification(
                                          customerId: customerId)));
                                } else {
                                  // Registering customer
                                  // Registering customer device info
                                  
                                  // and navigating the user to otpverification page

                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => OtpVerification(
                                          customerId: customerId)));
                                }
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.green.shade300,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Otp Screen

```
return Scaffold
 ....
PinEntryTextField(
                fieldWidth: 60.0,
                showFieldAsBox: true,
                onSubmit: (String pin) async {
                  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  
                  // redirected to menu page

                  final optData =
                      OtpModel(customerId: widget.customerId, otp: pin);

                  final result = await loginServices.otpVerify(optData);
                  if (result['existsFlag'] == '1') {
                    // setting customer prefs
                    prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);

                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuPage()));
                
                  } else {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: null,
                          content: Text('неверный код подтверждения '),
                        );
                      },
                    ); //end showDialog()
                  }
                  // ...............................
                  // showDialog(
                  //   context: context,
                  //   builder: (context) {
                  //     return AlertDialog(
                  //       title: Text("Pin"),
                  //       content: Text('Pin entered is $pin'),
                  //     );
                  //   },
                  // ); //end showDialog()
                  // ...............................
                }, // end onSubmit
              ),
```

Menu Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

// ... Constants
import '../constants.dart';

// ... Providers
import '../providers/order_notify.dart';

// ... Models
import '../models/cart_order.dart';
import '../models/menu_model.dart';

// ... API'S
import '../apis/api_response.dart';
import '../apis/menu-api.dart';

// ... Pages
import '../pages/menu_detail.dart';

class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Products pro;

  MenuPage({Key key, this.pro}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  ProductApi get productsServices => GetIt.I<ProductApi>();

  APIResponse<List<Products>> _apiResponse;

  bool _isLoading = false;

  void _fetchProducts() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    _apiResponse = await productsServices.getProductsList();

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  hasDiscount(product) {
    return product.hasDiscount == '1'
        ? product.priceAfter
        : product.hasDiscount == '0'
            ? product.priceBefore
            : product.priceAfter;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: kDefaultPadding, vertical: kDefaultPadding),
                  child: Text('Меню', style: kStyleHeaders),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Builder(builder: (_) {
                  if (_isLoading) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200.0),
                      child: Center(child: null),
                    );
                  }
                  if (_apiResponse.error) {
                    return Center(child: Text(_apiResponse.errorMessage));
                  }
                  if (_apiResponse.data.length == 0) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'No products has been found..!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: _apiResponse.data.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.72,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var product = _apiResponse.data[index];
                      return CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: product.imageMedium,
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Column(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ProductDetail(
                                      id: product.id,
                                      title: product.title,
                                      description: product.description,
                                      structure: product.structure,
                                      imageLarge: product.imageLarge,
                                      weight: product.weight,
                                      hasDiscount: product.hasDiscount,
                                      priceBefore:
                                          double.parse(product.priceBefore),
                                      priceAfter:
                                          double.parse(product.priceAfter),
                                      isHit: product.isHit,
                                      isNew: product.isNew,
                                      isSpicy: product.isSpicy,
                                      isRecommended: product.isRecommended,
                                      isVegetarian: product.isVegetarian,
                                      attributes: product.attributes),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment(-1, 0.9),
                                child: (product.isNew == '1')
                                    ? Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/new.png',
                                        width: 60.0,
                                      )
                                    : null,
                                height: 165.0,
                                width: 165.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 0,
                                        offset: Offset(0, 2))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                      child: Text(product.title,
                                          style: kStyleTitle))
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                      product.weight != null
                                          ? product.weight
                                          : '',
                                      style: kStyleWeight),
                                  Text(
                                      product.hasDiscount != '0'
                                          ? product.priceBefore
                                          : '',
                                      style: kStyleDiscount),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
                                    height: 30.0,
                                    width: 70.0,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        // ... Todo
                                        context.read<OrderNotify>().addOrder(
                                              CartOrder(
                                                  product: product,
                                                  qty: 1,
                                                  price: hasDiscount(product)),
                                            );
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(hasDiscount(product),
                                              style: kStylePrice),
                                          Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.rubleSign,
                                            size: 13.0,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xffB81F33)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(
                          Icons.error,
                          size: 40.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// ... API'S
import './apis/category-api.dart';
import './apis/menu-api.dart';
import './apis/promotion-api.dart';
import './apis/login-api.dart';
import './apis/ipaddress-api.dart';
import './apis/deviceinfo-api.dart';
import './apis/customer_deviceinfo-api.dart';

// Providers
import './providers/order_notify.dart';

import 'app.dart';

void setupLocator() {
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => PromotionApi());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => CategoriesApi());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => ProductApi());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => LoginApi());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => IPAddressInfo());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => DeviceInfo());
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton(() => CustomerDeviceInfoApi());
}

void setDeviceInfo() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  DeviceInfo deviceServices = GetIt.I<DeviceInfo>();
  IPAddressInfo ipServices = GetIt.I<IPAddressInfo>();

  prefs.setString('ipAddress', await ipServices.getIPAddress());
  prefs.setString('manufacturerModel', await deviceServices.getPhoneInfo());
  prefs.setString('deviceVersion', await deviceServices.getPhoneVersion());
  prefs.setString('os', await deviceServices.getOperatingSystem());
  prefs.setString(
      'screenResolution', await deviceServices.getScreenResolution());
  prefs.setString('packageOrBundle', await deviceServices.getPackageName());
  prefs.setString('appVersion', await deviceServices.getAppVersion());
  prefs.setString('isPhysical',
      await deviceServices.isPhysicalDevice() == true ? '1' : '0');
  prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', false);
}

void main() {
  // ... setup shared prefrences
  // ... todo
  // ... get device informaton set shared prefrences
  // ... todo

  // ... Setuploacator
  setupLocator();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => OrderNotify(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );

  setDeviceInfo();
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isStartHomePage = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      // If the page has not jump over the jump page
      if (!isStartHomePage) {
        // Go Home and destroy the current page
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => App(),
            ),
            (Route<dynamic> rout) => false);
        isStartHomePage = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/stripes_min.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/Buffet_Logo_Trans_min.png',
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// ... APP Helpers
import '../helpers/app_helper.dart';

// ... Pages
import '../pages/home_page.dart';
import '../pages/promotions_page.dart';
import '../pages/menu_page.dart';
import '../pages/more_page.dart';
import '../pages/orders_page.dart';
import '../pages/cart.dart';

// ... Providers
import '../providers/order_notify.dart';

// ... Widgets
import '../widgets/badge.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  // Current Index set to 0
  int currentTabIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(
      key: PageStorageKey('HomePage'),
    ),
    PromotionsPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('PromoPage'),
    ),
    MenuPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('MenuOage'),
    ),
    OrdersPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Orderpage'),
    ),
    MorePage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Morepage'),
    ),
    Cart(
      key: PageStorageKey('CartPage'),
    )
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  // Current page
  Widget currentPage;

  void setTabIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTabIndex = index;
      currentPage = pages[index];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Helper.launchUrl('tel:88007073566');
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.call,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 25.0,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'BUFFET',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: 'BuffetBold'),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            width: 60,
            child: Badge(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cart()));
                },
              ),
              value: context.watch<OrderNotify>().items.length.toString(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[currentTabIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) {
          setTabIndex(index);
        },
        currentIndex: currentTabIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        selectedFontSize: 0,
        unselectedFontSize: 0,
        iconSize: 30,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 28),
        unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(1),
        selectedLabelStyle:
            Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.merge(TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                )),
        unselectedLabelStyle:
            Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.merge(TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                )),
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
            ),
            label: 'Главная',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_outlined),
            label: 'Акции',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant),
            label: 'Меню',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.av_timer),
            label: 'Заказы',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            label: 'Еще',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

App.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ... Constants
import 'constants.dart';

// ... Screens
import './screens/main_screen.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Buffet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        fontFamily: 'Buffet',
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: I have added code above

Comment: can you also provide the code for `MenuPage` ?

Comment: @adnan i have added it

Comment: well, your `MainPage` returns a `scaffold`, which only contains `body`

Comment: @adnan Can you please explain more. because i have stuck on this problem for about 3 days now, i can't find any explanation to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you pushed `MenuPage` to stack in `OtpScreen`

```
Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuPage()));
```

You should pop the otp page or navigate to `MainScreen` that contains your `PageStorage`